# Image not saved to Contacts of the device

Tags: ios, swift3, airdrop

Hi i am creating new contact using CNMutableContact() and adding few details as below.

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
contact.givenName = “John”
let image = UIImage(named: "school")
let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
contact.imageData = imgData
```

Using the fallowing function i am sharing the contact via Airdrop to any other device.

```
func shareContacts(contacts: [CNMutableContact]) throws {

    guard let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return
    }

    var filename = NSUUID().uuidString

     if let contact = contacts.first, contacts.count == 1 {

        if let fullname = CNContactFormatter().string(from: contact) {
            filename = fullname.components(separatedBy: "").joined(separator: "")

        }
    }



    let fileURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathExtension("vcf")

    let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: contacts)

    print("filename: \(filename)")
    print("contact: \(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))")



    try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomicWrite)
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [fileURL],
        applicationActivities: nil
    )

     present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if completed == true {
             print("Saved")

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

 }
```

In the receiver device the contact is getting saved to the device contacts but the image is not saved.
What wrong i am doing that is preventing the image to get saved?